# Failed to install plugins in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install `domain-availability` on the Laravel project but this is the result

```html
PS C:\..\workspace v2> composer require helgesverre/domain-availability
Using version ^1.4 for helgesverre/domain-availability
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - helgesverre/domain-availability 1.4.0 requires jeremykendall/php-domain-parser ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jeremykendall/php-domain-parser[3.x-dev].
    - helgesverre/domain-availability v1.4.1 requires jeremykendall/php-domain-parser ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jeremykendall/php-domain-parser[3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install jeremykendall/php-domain-parser 3.x-dev
    - Installation request for helgesverre/domain-availability ^1.4 -> satisfiable by helgesverre/domain-availability[1.4.0, v1.4.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
PS C:\..\workspace v2>
```

I'm using this library
https://github.com/HelgeSverre/Domain-Availability

and i activated `extension=intl` in `php.ini` file

and install `jeremykendall/php-domain-parser` using command

```
composer require jeremykendall/php-domain-parser
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: clear the cache of composer and try again or even can try with write package in composer file and run composer install command.

Comment: I tried this and did not solve the problem

Comment: Is the package jeremykendall/php-domain-parser currently installed ?

Comment: yes,the result when try reinstall 
Using version ^5.4 for jeremykendall/php-domain-parser
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader